# Aptana smarty support?

Tags: php, smarty, aptana

Is there any way to make aptana (2 or 3) support smarty ? Code color, etc..
I read people talking about how they like to have smarty support in Aptana 3 as in Aptana 2, but i don't find it even for Aptana 2!
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe SmartyPDT will help? Not sure if it will work with Aptana, though. http://code.google.com/p/smartypdt/

Comment: I know, it's the first thing i found, but i was wondering too if it works with aptana. Thx

Comment: Seems like no Smarty in Aptana 3 yet. Here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264579/is-there-any-support-for-smarty-in-aptana-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just installed smartypdt http://code.google.com/p/smartypdt/ on Aptana 2.
Just go to help > install new software then click on "add" and choose the zip file you just downloaded. Uncheck "group items by category" then check the new smarty package that just appeared and keep clicking next .
Make sur the .tpl are not associated with other formats.

Comment: This will work... you may need to install also the TDLK stuff from the normal Eclipse Indigo update site.

Answer (score 4):

You can associate .tpl files from within explorer by right clicking a .tpl file and going to properties and “open with” and selecting/browsing to Aptana.

you need to go to “Window” -> “Preferences” -> “General” -> “Content Types” and select “Text” in the right text pane, browse down to “HTML” and click the “Add” button and add “*.tpl” to the extensions list.