# Is there any support for Smarty in Aptana 3?

Tags: php, smarty, aptana, aptana3

It seems Aptana 3 still doesn't support Smarty, as it did in version 2... is there any third party plugin/hack to get it working?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955968/aptana-smarty-support

Answer (score 0):

Smarty is not yet supported in Aptana Studio 3. There is a ticket for that at http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-1465

No third party plugins that I know or were created yet, as the Studio's editor infrastructure was completely redesigned.